# How to iterate through an array starting from the last element? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I came with below solution but I believe that must be nicer one out there ...

```
array = [ 'first','middle','last']

index = array.length
array.length.times { index -= 1; puts array[index]}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
array.reverse.each { |x| puts x }
```

Comment: I knew there would be something `nice` ... Thank you.

Comment: Actually, `reverse_each` is better because it doesn't make a copy of the array as `reverse` does.

Comment: Yes, I would also expect that `reverse_each` is better, though I haven't dug into the internals to see for myself.

Comment: Important note per some algos I just did: `.reverse` will actually reverse the array (returning a newly reversed array and when iterating you're still going front->back). `.reverse_each` on the other hand, will actually traverse backwards without actually reversing the array.

Answer (score 109):

Ruby is smart

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.reverse_each {|x| print x, " " }
```

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to iterate through a range in reverse then use:

```
(0..5).reverse_each do |i|
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Does `#reverse_each` perform a reverse operation internally?  Or does it just start at the end and work backwards?  If the latter, this answer could achieve better time complexity than first calling `#reverse` and then `#each` separately, since `#reverse` is essentially a sort operation of O(n log n) while counting from last to first is the same as `#each` in terms of time complexity (i.e. O(n)).

Comment: @RichieThomas reverse.each is the O(nlogn) but reverse_each just iterates from the last element to the first

Answer (score 4):

If you want to achieve the same without using reverse [Sometimes this question comes in interviews]. We need to use basic logic.

1. array can be accessed through index
2. set the index to length of array and then decrements by 1 until index reaches 0
3. output to screen or a new array or use the loop to perform any logic.

   ```
       def reverseArray(input)
         output = []
         index = input.length - 1 #since 0 based index and iterating from 
         last to first

         loop do
           output << input[index]
           index -= 1
           break if index < 0
         end

         output
       end

       array = ["first","middle","last"]

       reverseArray array #outputs: ["last","middle","first"]
   ```

Comment: Why not use just reverse_each?

Answer (score 3):

You can even use a for loop

```
array = [ 'first','middle','last']
for each in array.reverse do
   print array
end
```

will print

```
last
middle
first
```

Comment: Actually it prints: ["first", "middle", "last"]["first", "middle", "last"]["first", "middle", "last"]

Answer (score 0):

In a jade template you can use:

```
for item in array.reverse()
   item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "unshift" method to iterate and add items to new "reversed" array.
Unshift will add a new item to the beginning of an array.
While << - adding in the end of an array. Thats why unshift here is good.

```
array = [ 'first','middle','last']
output = []
                             # or: 
for item in array            #     array.each do |item|
  output.unshift(item)       #       output.unshift(item)            
end                          #     end

puts "Reversed array: #{output}"
```

will print: ["last", "middle", "first"]

Answer (score 0):

We can also use "until":

```
index = array.length - 1
    
until index == -1
   p  arr[index]
   index -= 1
end
```