# how to iterate through array from the last element in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to iterate through an array starting from the last element? (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346166/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-starting-from-the-last-element-ruby)

I am trying to iterate over a list in reverse, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
presidents = ["Ford", "Carter", "Reagan", "Bush1", "Clinton", "Bush2"]

for ss in -presidents.length...0
    print  ": ", presidents[ss], "\n";
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [reverse_each](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse_each)

```
presidents = ["Ford", "Carter", "Reagan", "Bush1", "Clinton", "Bush2"]
presidents.reverse_each { |president| p president }
```

Comment: oh, I prefer your method to mine

Answer (score 0):

```
presidents = ["Ford", "Carter", "Reagan", "Bush1", "Clinton", "Bush2"]

presidents.reverse.each do |president|
  puts president
end
```

Comment: reverse.each makes a copy of the array. You should use reverse_each

Comment: if I wanna do the same with array contains numbers .can I apply the same

Comment: @AdamHarte thanks for the tip. Kishore, you can do this with numbers too. But you should know that there is a difference between `numbers = [1, 2, 3]` and `numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]`. In the first array, numbers are Integers and in the second, they are Strings.

Comment: @AdamHarte thank you for the response .Its very useful .

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
(presidents.length-1).step(0,-1) {|i| p presidents[i]}
```