# How can I go through an array and still remove elements from it

Tags: ruby

[How to iterate through an array starting from the last element? (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346166/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-starting-from-the-last-element-ruby)
Looks similar but removing elements seems to causing lots of problems such it has no effect.
It is RGSS so use really simple code.

```
ptl=[[0,3],[1,5],[2],[3,14],[4,0],[5,0],[6,15],[7,9],[8,7],[9,11],[10,16],[11,6],[12],[13,9],[14],[15,14]]

    ps=ptl.sample(3)
    
    pt=(ps[0]+ps[1]+ps[2])
    for i in (ptl.length()-1)..0
         if ptl[i]&ps
            if (ptl[i][0]==pt[j])
                ptl[i]=[]
            end
            if ptl[i][1]==pt[j]
                ptl[i]=[]
            end
            
        end
    end
```

Comment: Your question should be, "Why is it a bad idea to remove elements from an array whilst iterating through it"? The answer can be seen by executing `a = [1,2,3,4,5]; a.each_with_index { |n,i| puts "a = #{a}, n = #{n}, i = #{i}"; a.pop }` then `a = [1,2,3,4,5]; a.each_with_index { |n,i| puts "a = #{a}, n = #{n}, i = #{i}"; a.shift }`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you also explain what your code is supposed to do and what doesn’t work as expected?

Comment: I have no idea what this is supposed to do but let's focus on some oddities. 1. `(ptl.length()-1)..0` this creates a Range of `15..0` which will have 0 elements e.g. `(15..0).to_a => []`. 2) `if ptl[i]&ps` this condition will always evaluate to true because `Array#&` will never return a falsey value (`nil` or `false`). 3) `j` the `j` variable does not exist. 4) both nested `if` conditions result in the same outcome? 5) At no point in this code are you removing variables as the title would suggest.

Comment: ptl[i]=[] is alternative statement of removing an element.